# Does Google Play Services Classpath necessary for device that has no Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using Firebase dependencies that do not require Play Services like Firestore and already manage to run it without any problem. So I am wondering if adding `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'` would still be necessary since the device I am targeting does not have it but removing it fails the build.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this library is necessary if you want to use Firebase.